# Extract Float Value or Integer Value from string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have been searching on SO to find out how to achieve what I want. I've seen answers but none for what I want:

```
str = "hello £25,500.98 and $5656.99"
str.match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0] # => "500.98". Close but not what I want.

str.scan(/\d/).join('') # Seems to combine all numbers - no.
```

**I expect to get** `25500.98`. Anything after the last digit will be discarded (hope I make sense here). I'm rubbish at regex. I think I've tried many variations in the rails console but nothing comes near except `str.match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0]`

Comment: First, a good place to debug ruby regex's is http://www.rubular.com/

Comment: @nPn Never knew about that site. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the commas before matching:

```
str.delete(',').match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0]
```

Comment: deleting the `,` is smart :)

Comment: What's the difference between `scan` and `match`? One is faster?

Comment: @Sylar, `scan` returns an array of strings with all matches. `match` returns a match object with the first match.

Answer (score 0):

Try the regexp:

```
[£$](\d+,\d+\.\d+|\d+\.\d+|\d+)
```

---

```
str.scan(/[£$]\d+,\d+\.\d+|\d+\.\d+|\d+/).each{|item| item.gsub!(/[£$,]/, '')}
```

[Example](http://www.rubular.com/r/fyP6FaV4Zz)